# Maximum chromatic number of a $k$-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $c_k$ be the maximum chromatic number that a $k$-regular graph can have. What is $\lim\sup_{k\to\infty}\frac{c_k}{k}$?

Comment: Uh, the chromatic number is bounded by the maximal degree plus one, so $c_k\leq k+1$, but conversely the complete graph on $k+1$ vertices shows that $c_k\geq k+1$. What did I miss?

Comment: I would also like to mention the upper bound can be easily shown with a greedy algorithm, no need to appeal to any theorems for just that.

Comment: @Dominic: In the past 10 days, you've asked 11 questions and currently the average vote on them is lower than 1 positive vote. I think you should think a little bit more about your questions before posting them, or consider posting some of them on math.stackexchange.com. This is particularly true of your questions in graph theory (or perhaps I just know more about this area); many, if not most of them, admit examples/counterexamples of very small order that could be found by anyone who actually spent a few minutes thinking about it.

Comment: @verret I absolutely agree - my apologies

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for the reasons pointed out ib @verret's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) with $k+1$  vertices (which is strongly $k$-regular) has degree $k$ and chromatic number $k+1$. On the other hand, by [Brook's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) this is the maximum possible value for the chromatic number of a $k$-regular graph, so $$\limsup_k \frac{c_k}{k} = \lim_k \frac{c_k}{k}=1.$$